# how to split large text files into smaller text files using vba?

Tags: sql, vba

I have a database textfile.
It is large text file about 387,480 KB. This file contains table name, headers of the table and values. I need to split this file into multiple files each containing table creation and insertion with a file name as table name. 
Please can anyone help me??

Comment: SQL itself has no such functionality. Perhaps SQL Server has? Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how Excel will open a 347MB file.  You can try to load it into Access, and do the split, using VBA.  However, the process of importing a file that large may fragment enough to blow Access up to @GB, and then it's all over.  SQL Server would handle this kind of job.  Alternatively, you could use Python or R to do the work for you.

```
### Python:
import pandas as pd
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('C:/your_path/main.csv', chunksize=3)):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i))

### R
setwd("C:/your_path/") 
mydata = read.csv("annualsinglefile.csv") 

# If you want 5 different chunks with same number of lines, lets say 30.
# Chunks = split(mydata,sample(rep(1:5,30)))  ## 5 Chunks of 30 lines each

# If you want 100000 samples, put any range of 20 values within the range of number of rows
First_chunk <- sample(mydata[1:100000,])  ## this would contain first 100000 rows

# Or you can print any number of rows within the range
# Second_chunk <- sample(mydata[100:70,] ## this would contain last 30 rows in reverse order if your data had 100 rows.

# If you want to write these chunks out in a csv file:
write.csv(First_chunk,file="First_chunk.csv",quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
# write.csv(Second_chunk,file="Second_chunk.csv",quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
```